# Montar um script c++

Tags: c++, script

Olá,eu queria montar um script em c++ capaz de detectar a cor do pixel sobre o cursor e se detectar executar a função click
Aqui pra detectar a cor do pixel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307526/get-pixel-color-at-mouse-position-fastest-way

Aqui pra clicar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379375/mouse-click-with-c

Até achei esses artigos,mas n sei montar o código e eu também queria usar cores mais específicas

Como posso montar o código?